# How can i use three identical figures in fabric js canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I didn't understand how to create three figures with the same size, but different color.

Help is needed in correctly putting the names of functions and other things, I myself do not know how to do it correctly.

HTML FILE it only needs to be edited in DIV CLASS="BOX"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>TEST</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="box">
  <div class="data_list">
    <div class="data_item rect" draggable="true" ondragstart="onDragstart('rect')"></div>
    <div class="data_item rectgreen" draggable="true" ondragstart="onDragstart('rect')"></div>
    <div class="data_item rectred" draggable="true" ondragstart="onDragstart('rect')"></div>
  </div>
  <canvas id="c" style="border: 2px solid #ccc;"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="fabric.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS FILE it okay

```
 .box {
      display: flex;
    }
    .data_list {
      width: 100px;
      margin-left: 10px;
    }
    .data_item {
      width: 60px;
      height: 40px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .data_item {
      width: 60px;
      height: 40px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .data_item {
      width: 60px;
      height: 40px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
```

js file it is need to be edit at switch (currentType) and function create

```
let currentElType = null 
let canvas = null

function initCanvas() {
    
    canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
      width: 1000,
      height: 700
    })

    
 
    canvas.on('mouse:down', function (opt) {
      var evt = opt.e;
      if (evt.altKey === true) {
        this.isDragging = true
        this.lastPosX = evt.clientX
        this.lastPosY = evt.clientY
      }
    })

    canvas.on('mouse:move', function (opt) {
      if (this.isDragging) {
        var e = opt.e;
        var vpt = this.viewportTransform;
        vpt[4] += e.clientX - this.lastPosX
        vpt[5] += e.clientY - this.lastPosY
        this.requestRenderAll()
        this.lastPosX = e.clientX
        this.lastPosY = e.clientY
      }
    })

    canvas.on('mouse:up', function (opt) {
      this.setViewportTransform(this.viewportTransform)
      this.isDragging = false
    })


    
    canvas.on('mouse:wheel', opt => {
      const delta = opt.e.deltaY 
      let zoom = canvas.getZoom() 
      zoom *= 0.999 ** delta
      if (zoom > 20) zoom = 20 
      if (zoom < 0.01) zoom = 0.01 

  
      canvas.zoomToPoint(
        { 
          x: opt.e.offsetX,
          y: opt.e.offsetY
        },
        zoom 
      )
    })
  }

  initCanvas()

  function onDragstart(type) {
    currentType = type
  }

  canvas.on('drop', function(opt) {

   
    let offset = {
      left: canvas.getSelectionElement().getBoundingClientRect().left,
      top: canvas.getSelectionElement().getBoundingClientRect().top
    }

    let point = {
      x: opt.e.x - offset.left,
      y: opt.e.y - offset.top,
    }

    let pointerVpt = canvas.restorePointerVpt(point)

    switch (currentType) {
      case 'rect':
        createRect(pointerVpt.y, pointerVpt.x)
        break
      case 'rect':
        createRectGreen(pointerVpt.y, pointerVpt.x)
        break
      case 'rect':
        createRectRed(pointerVpt.y, pointerVpt.x)
        break
    }
    currentElType = null
  })

  function createRect(top, left) {
    canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
      top,
      left,
      width: 60,
      height: 40,
      fill: 'blue'
    }))
  }
  function createRectGreen(top, left) {
    canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
      top,
      left,
      width: 60,
      height: 40,
      fill: 'green'
    }))
  }
  function createRectRed(top, left) {
    canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
      top,
      left,
      width: 60,
      height: 40,
      fill: 'red'
    }))
  }
```

I just try to make figures with the same title in js

Comment: What exactly is not working? And what do you mean by “help is needed in correctly putting the names of functions and other things” ? Please clarify what exactly the problem is.

Comment: @Kokodoko I meant that now when I want to take a red rectangle from a sheet, I take blue (I have all the figures as if blue). I suspect that I incorrectly entered the name of the functions and other information.

Comment: In your switch case you check for `rect` three times, you should use the switch to check for the color of the dragged rectangle. Also, in your `onDragStart` you always pass `rect` for all three rectangles, so the code can never know which of the three rectangles you dragged.

Comment: @Kokodoko so what i need to change

Comment: Each draggable square passes the same `rect` value, you could change it to `red`, `blue` and `green` for start. If that works you can edit your `switch` function to check for `red`, `blue` and `green` instead of checking the same `rect` three times.